# Using material.io lists in android

Tags: android, layout, material-design, material-components-android, google-material-icons

According to the newest maven [website](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-beta01) the newest material.io version is: `com.google.android.material.material-1.4.0-beta01`

Which I did import:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-beta01'
```

According to the [documenttation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/lists/package-summary?hl=uk), listviews are already available in material.io.

However according to my XML-Layoutfile, there are no `.lists.` classes, how can that be?
Am I missing some import?
[image: inj]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The components provided by the package `com.google.android.material.lists` are [**not**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/build.gradle) included in the `1.4.0` version.

In any case, the current components are only [`ViewHolder`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/lists):

- `SingleLineItemViewHolder`
- `TwoLineItemViewHolder`
- `ThreeLineItemViewHolder`

Comment: @Gabrielle Mariotti, thanks for the answer. So I just need to copy the class and add it to my xml file then, or do I need to be carefully when doing so?

Comment: @SavanLuffy Here an example: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/lists/ListsMainDemoFragment.java. You have to copy the classes but also the resources.